# Create a div that expands to contain one block, but let's another block flow outside it

Tags: css, overflow, block

CSS still always catches me...

I want to have a block that automatically expands to contain some child content, but let's another child flow out of it.  That is:

```
<div class='no-expansion-from-big-child'>
  <p>This is a block with content, and a child div.</p>
  <div class='big-child'>
    <p>This is a child-block - I want it to overflow outside the borders of its containing div.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So if I have a border around my containing div, I want it to expand to enclose the "p" block, but allow the 'big-child' div to extend beyond the border.

Seems like it should be simple...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is really what you're looking after, however you could float the second child div and give the container an [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow) of `visible` to make sure that it won't contain the floated child:

```css
.no-expansion-from-big-child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: visible;
}

.big-child {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='no-expansion-from-big-child'>
  <p>This is a block with content, and a child div.</p>
  <div class='big-child'>
    <p>This is a child-block - I want it to overflow outside the borders of its containing div.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```